# How to get working markdown with code blocks included in django

Tags: python, django

i want to know if there's a package or installation that I can install or get in django that allows me to do markdown. I know there are many posts in Stackoverflow like this, but none of them work or help, and this is separate. The requirements that I need in the installation are:

- must allow bold text using `**text**`
- must allow italics using `_text_`
- must allow comments using `> text`
- must allow bullets using `- text`
- must allow formatting using ``
- must allow code blocks like:

````py
```python
def function():
  return something
````

so for the code blocks, when I put ` and a language following, it must highlight the text inside.

more or less the installation should be like StackOverflow markdown.

So please let me know if you have a package or installation or something that enables me to get markdown in django.

Thanks!

Comment: Does https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/ fit for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want how the process is to work, and if this would work properly, also I want to know how to work this in my forms in django, like would I use a template tag in the templates? Please let me know this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sovereign, provide some sample code of what you've tried so far. Markdown is the package you want if you are storing markdown text and want to display it in your templates. If you want editable fields with color highlighting, then you are more likely needed a javascript package like https://codemirror.net/ (or similar).

Comment: so for example say i have this variable in the templates `{{ something.content }}`. If i installed markdown, i would be able to do `{{ something.content|markdown }}` that's the tag. So now in the content field, when i run it, it enables me to use markdown with all my requirements. I want something like that, but if you have a similar one, please provide. So for the codemirror.net, i know i have to get the link and the code in there, but could you tell me how to use it so that it enables it in the content section? Thanks!